# How to have file name and line number in GAE Python logging.info logs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

In the logs, the timestamp is available but the `"source file name"` and `"line number"` are not logged with every log message.

How to log file name and line number in GAE Python `logging.info` (or `logging.warn` or `logging.error` and others) ?

By `"source file name"`, I mean the Python code file (*.py) which generated the log.

Answer (score 1):

In your `main.py` add:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s')

logging.getLogger().handlers[0].setFormatter(formatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at [logging formatters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) ?

It should look something like this

```
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '[%(asctime)s] p%(process)s {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d}'
    ' %(levelname)s - %(message)s','%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```